# How to get UriTemplate of a Rest Services

Tags: web-services, wcf, rest, c#-4.0

I am trying to make a web service testing tool in C# 4.0,
For RestFull Services When the URI template is same as that of parameter name then I am able to hit the service
eg,

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "JSONDate/{id}"
            )]
 string JSONDate(string id);
```

Note: here method name and Uri template are same.

But if URI template is not same as the method name and parameter then I am not able to hit the services,
eg

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "myXMLData/{id}/{id2}/{value}")]
        string XMLData(string Id,string id2,string value);
```

Also the fact that URI template can be designed in multiple ways possess a challenge in setting up the request string.

Is there any way that I can get the URI template so that I can design my request string by parsing the URI template.

Comment: UriTemplate doesn't depend on your method name. It could be any. But parameter names must match. Like string Id and {id} do not match with each other.

Comment: Well it does matters.
like calling http://address/Service1.svc/XMLData/1111/222/12
will fail as here I am calling "XMLData" and in URI template it is "myXMLData"

Comment: No it doesn't matter :) . You are calling it incorrect.  address/Service1.svc/myXMLData/1111/222/12 will definitely hit. If it doesn't then you must have done something wrong.

Comment: yes calling  address/Service1.svc/myXMLData/1111/222/12 does hit.thats what I am asking. 

see if you read it again what i am saying is : I am able to get the method name and parameter names but the not able to get the URI template, if some how I could get the URI template then I can target any rest service from my tool

Comment: you want UriTemplate before you actually hit the Service Uri?

Comment: Yes if that is possible, so that according to URI template I can format my request string

Comment: Well! I don't think so. But may be WSDL help you.

Comment: tried WSDL but didn't turned out

Comment: But why you need to get the UriTemplate? Make a base request and then append the required Uris at the end as per need.

Comment: I am trying to make a generic web service testing tool, So if I have created the service I do know the URI template and can hit the services, But how some other guy has made his URI template and the way he is accepting parameters can vary

Comment: The WSDL will help your user. Other way is to provide document for your Service which is very much acceptable or provide RSS feeds.

Comment: hmm.. lets see... for the time being prime focus is on getting URI template..... thanks bhai jaan :)